# Memset on pointer of pointers - why won't it work?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, vector

I'm implementing a matrix library in c. I've already made a vector library and I have defined a matrix to be nothing but a collection of pointers pointing to vectors (so each pointer references a vector struct which is the matrices column.) I have a pointer of pointers instead of an array of pointers because a) I want jagged matrices to be possible b) I want vector operations to work on the individual columns of the matrix and c) I want the actual matrix to be dynamic.

Here is the matrix type definition:

```
    typedef struct mat {
    size_t alloc; // num of allocated bytes
    size_t w, h; // dimensions for the matrix
    vec** cols; // each column is a vector
    } mat;
```

Suppose I want to resize the dimensions of the matrix. The following code works just fine for me:

```
    void resizem(mat* m, size_t w, size_t h) {
    m -> alloc = w * VECTOR_SIZE;
    m -> cols = realloc(m -> cols, m -> alloc);
//    if(w > m -> w) {
//        memset(m -> cols + m -> w, init_vec(h), (w - (m -> w)) * VECTOR_SIZE);
//    }
    if(w > m -> w) {
        for(int i = m -> w; i < w; i++) {
            m -> cols[i] = init_vec(h);
        };
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        resizev(m -> cols[i], h);
    };
    m -> w = w;
    m -> h = h;
}
```

My approach was as follows: 1) re-compute the amount of bytes to reallocate and store this in the matrix struct (amount of columns * column size) 2) reallocate  memory to the columns 3) if the matrix 'grew' in width then each new column needs to be initialised to a default vector. 4) resize the size of each vector in the matrix.

Note the commented out lines however. **Why can't I just add an offset (the size of the former matrix) to the column pointers and use memset on the remaining columns to initialise them to a default vector? When I run this it doesn't work so I use a for loop instead.**

*Note that if it helps at all here is the github link to the vector library so far: [Github link](https://github.com/topologicalhurt/c-vectors)*

Comment: Please don't put spaces around `->`. It's not idiomatic and hard for experienced programmers to read.

Comment: “it doesn't work” is not a problem description. Edit the question to provide a [mre], including sample observed output (or other observed program behavior) and the desired output. Note that `memset` sets every byte to a value. It cannot be used to initialize multibyte types like pointers, `int` objects, or floating-point objects unless the desired value is represented with the same bits in every byte (notably zero).

Comment: `void**` is very likely the wrong type to use for pretty much any purpose. You could use `void*` if you point at a "mangled" array of unknown type - that is a 2D array allocated as a 1D array with indices calculated in run-time. But `void*` is not a useful type for such, since you cannot do poiner arithmetic on it. Maybe you are looking for `uint8_t*`. Or alternatively you could use a flexible array member, which might be what you actually want to do here.

Comment: @Lundin: There is no `void` in the question except as the return type of a function, where it is just `void`, not `void**`. Did you misread `vec**`?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `memset()` you only call `initvec()` once. So all the elements would point to the *same* vector.

Also, `memset()` assigns the value to each byte in the array. But your row is supposed to contain pointers, not bytes.

BTW, your code is leaking lots of memory, because you never `free()` the old pointers in the row. You need to do this before calling `realloc()`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a function like memset that works on pointers instead of bytes? Also thanks for the heads up. I will fix that

Comment: No, there isn't. And even if there were, you would stll have the first problem I pointed out.

Comment: alright. Thanks v much. I've only just started out in c so obviously I suck but I guess everyone starts somewhere.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up. It's a common mistake.

Comment: Hey barmar sorry to bother you but I'm a little confused about what you meant exactly by what's causing the memory leak. In my mind isn't it just reallocating the memory and I thought that took care of memory leaks tself.

Comment: You're reallocating `m->cols`, but not all the vectors it points to.

Comment: I assume `init_vec()` is calling `malloc()` in a loop. You need to free all of them.